# Bash signal capture not detecting variables changed after declaration of 'trap' block

Tags: bash, shell, scope, bash-trap

I have a bunch of generic cleanup code that needs to be done whenever a certain bash script exits, whether it exited normally or was interrupted. I figured I'd use the `trap "..." EXIT` pseudosignal to achieve this.

In addition to the generic cleanup stuff, there's also one piece of specific cleanup that should only be done if the script completes normally. I thought I could trigger this by having the 'trap' block test a variable, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
done=false;
trap "{        
           #generic cleanup code goes here.
           if $done
           then
               #cleanup to be done only on completion goes here.
               echo Test;
           fi
       }" EXIT
#main script goes here
done=true;
```

However, this doesn't work. Running the following code will never echo "Test". Adding an explicit `exit` call after `done=true;` doesn't change anything. What am I missing?

Cheers!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The trap is being interpolated, and is using the value of $done at the time the trap is being defined rather than when it is executed. You can use single quotes around the trap definition, or define a function.  Defining a function is probably cleaner:

```
#!/bin/sh
done=false
cleanup() { if test "$done" = true; then echo Test; fi; }
trap cleanup EXIT
done=true
```

This works because the expansion of variables in the function is deferred until the function is called, rather than when the function is defined.

Comment: I wonder is it signal safe. Say if signal arrives between last command of initialization and `done=true` assignment.

Comment: @reddot That is a valid concern, but I'm not sure it's correct to use the phrase "signal safe".  It's just a race condition.  "signal safe" refers to something different.  (eg functions that are non-reentrant)

Comment: I agree with your terminology, it's better to use "race condition" phrase here. BTW I have opened a new question about the case -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676188/shell-traps-signals-and-conditional-cleanup . Maybe you have any ideas to share.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with `while true` like `i=0; cleanup(){echo $i;}; trap cleanup EXIT; while true; do i=$(($i+1)); done` ??

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed It does work, but your shell may not execute the trap on EXIT when it receives SIGINT.  Try `trap cleanup EXIT INT`  (and note that some shells may execute `cleanup` twice in response to SIGINT)

Comment: I really tested it with many signals `trap cleanup 1 2 3 4 6 9` and it echo only `0` ignoring the increment by `while true`

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed Interesting; which shell?

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed It works for me in `5.1.16(1)`, whether invoked as `bash` or `sh`.  Perhaps I misunderstand how you are sending the signal.  Try adding `echo $i` to the body of the do-loop to verify that it is incrementing.  Perhaps your example case is simplified, and `i` is incrementing in a subshell (is the `while loop` in a pipeline?)